# Generate binomial random variables based on inverse transformation in R

Tags: r, algorithm, random

It's my first coding course at uni, and I'm stuck with the two algorithms asked below.

I've been asked to develop an algorithm in R that generates binomional random variables based on the inverse transformation.
And to develop an algorithm again in R that generates Normal random variables based on the acceptance-rejection technique.

I've been looking around, but i'm not sure how to do it. I know there are internal R functions to generate random variables from different distributions (like: rnorm (n, mean, stddev) ) but I can't use them.

Comment: If you know what the inverse transformation method is, I guess you should not have any issue in implementing it. Since it's not clear if your question regards specifically programming aspects or theoretical ones, your question risks to be closed/moved. Specify what you know and  in which aspect you need help.

Comment: Demonstrating your effort so far is always useful for getting help. Describe the pseudo-code of inverse transformation, and include your code draft maybe?